# Time Complexity of a function that iterates over n repeated digits

Tags: function, loops, methods, time-complexity, big-o

Let's say I had a function

```
def f(n):

   for x in range(int("1" * n)):
       ....  # assume this step is o(1)
```

This function takes an integer n and then iterates over 1 repeated n times.

Example.

For n = 5

```
for i in range(11111): 
    pass
```

For n = 4

```
for i in range(1111):
    pass
```

What would the time complexity be for this function with input n and or how would you work it out?

Apologies if the question is not clear and thanks for all the help.

Comment: Well the time complexity would be `n` right since the loop is repeated `n` times?

Comment: No, if n = 3, the loop is repeated 111 times etc. @Flame

Comment: oh i see what it does now let me have a think

Comment: Seems like the complexity approaches `10^(n-1)`, 4 ~ 1000, 5 ~ 10000, 6 ~ 1000000, so exponential time

Comment: @Flame that's what I suspected, Is it ok to use approximations when working out time complexity though?

Comment: I would say that it is, the main idea is that this function grows incredibly fast (even a little faster than this approximation). I'm not sure if you can even create an exact formula for the relation between 1-11-111-1111-11111 (concatenation is not a nice mathematical operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an input of value `n`, the number of iterations will be `(10^n - 1)/9`.
So, the number of iterations increases of a factor of 10 with each addition to the input.

Also note that `n` is not the input size, but it's the value of the input, so the time complexity is double exponential as the input size is logarithmic in `n`.

Comment: ah thats an exact formula indeed :) i forgot about 10/9

Comment: Wow, thanks. Nice formula for number of iterations.